# Update touch position (slide) during time with Flame (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, touch, flame

in my game with Flame I have a space ship, and I want it to follow where I'm pressing with my finger. For the moment it goes to the first spot I touch until I leave the finger from the screen, but if I move keeping it on, it continues to follow where I initially pressed. Is there a way to update where my finger is(using HasTappableComponents)? Or should I change approach?

```
class SpaceFlame extends FlameGame with HasTappableComponents {
  late Ship ship;
  late TapHandler tapHandler;
  @override
  Future<void> onLoad() async {
    ship = Ship()
      ..position = Vector2(size.x / 2, size.y / 2)
      ..size = Vector2(64, 64)
      ..setSpeed(100);
    tapHandler = TapHandler();
    ship.anchor = Anchor.center;
    await addAll([
      Background(Palette.background),
      ship,
      tapHandler,
    ]);
  }

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(canvasSize.toRect(), Paint()..color = Palette.buttonBlu);
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    // TODO: implement update
    if (tapHandler.tapped) {
      print('tapped');
      Vector2 moveDirection = Vector2(
          tapHandler.tapPosition.x - ship.position.x,
          tapHandler.tapPosition.y - ship.position.y);
      ship.setMoveDirection(moveDirection);
    } else {
      ship.setMoveDirection(Vector2.zero());
    }
    super.update(dt);
  }
}

class TapHandler extends PositionComponent with TapCallbacks {
  TapHandler() : super(anchor: Anchor.center);

  bool tapped = false;
  Vector2 _tapPosition = Vector2.zero();

  final _paint = Paint()..color = const Color(0x00000000);

  @override
  void onGameResize(Vector2 canvasSize) {
    super.onGameResize(canvasSize);

    size = canvasSize;

    position = canvasSize / 2;
  }

  Vector2 get tapPosition => _tapPosition;

  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawRect(size.toRect(), _paint);
  }

  @override
  void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
    print('object');
    tapped = true;
    _tapPosition = event.canvasPosition;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you keep your finger on the screen and drag it the even is no longer a tap, but a drag.

To react to this event you need to use `HasDraggableComponents` on the game and `DragCallbacks` on the component. Then you need to implement `onDragUpdate` in your component and set the position to the position that the event reports for the drag.